# How to efficiently spawn a binary tree from certain nodes?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, graph-algorithm

Not sure if it is a proper place to ask for such question.. But I will just post it anyway...

Suppose I have a binary tree, which certain nodes marked as `red`:

```
     n1
    /  \
   red n2
   / \  \
  n3 n4  red
         / \
        n5 n6
```

So what I would like to do, is for every `red` node, spawn the tree into two new trees, and put each of the child into one tree.

So for the above case, it would become four trees like this:

```
  n1
 / \
n3  n2
    /
   n5

  n1
 / \
 n4 n2
    /
   n5

  n1
 / \
n3  n2
     \
     n6

  n1
 / \
 n4 n2
     \
     n6
```

It seems a pretty clean-defined problem.. but so far I just cannot come up with a good solution for this..

Could anyone shed some lights on this problem? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Do the unary brances, e.g. `n5` or `n6` have to specifically be a left and a right branch or can they be either? Also does it have to represented as a tree or can it be represented with `()`s. If so then convert to BNF and generate all the patterns, e.g. `S = A n1 (n2 B). A = n3 | n4. B = n5 | n6.`

Comment: Thank you @GuyCoder, `n5` and `n6` does not have to be in specific left and right. On the other hand, I found it is hard for me to get your point.. By any chance, could you elaborate it more..? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations that can lead to a clean implementation:

- if there are `n` red nodes, then there will be 2<sup>n</sup> trees (this ignores the situation where the red node is a leaf -- those probably don't matter and can be eliminated by a pre-processing step).
- any number `k` between 0 and 2<sup>n</sup> - 1 can represent one configuration -- the decision taken at the i<sup>th</sup> red node (*i.e.* whether to keep the left or the right sub-tree) is indicated by the i<sup>th</sup> bit of `k`. This bit can be easily obtained using bit-wise operations, *e.g.* by comparing `k & (1 << i)` with 0.

The main function that can generate trees one by one would look like this:

```
void spawnAllTrees(baseTree) {
    int nRed = countRedNodes(baseTree);

    // this assigns to each red node an index between 0 and nRed - 1
    // (e.g. according to a pre-order tree traversal). 
    // it computes a hash map denoted as "redIndex" which
    // stores the mapping from Node to int
    computeRedIndices(baseTree);

    for (int k = 0; k < (1 << nRed); k++) {
        crtTree = spawnTree(baseTree, k);
    }
}
```

The code for spawnTree would be:

```
Node spawnTree(baseTreeNode, k) {
    if (baseTreeNode.isRed()) {
        idx = redIndex[baseTreeNode];
        if (!bitIsSet(k, idx)) {
            return spawnTree(baseTreeNode->left(), k);
        } else {
            return spawnTree(baseTreeNode->right(), k);
    } else {
        return new Node(baseTreeNode->value(), 
                        spawnTree(baseTreeNode->left(), k), 
                        spawnTree(baseTreeNode->right(), k));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Changed the algorithm a little bit -- incrementing a counter to determine the current red node index is not valid. Different decisions at a certain red node could make another red node receive different indices for different configurations.

Comment: Fantastic. I haven't tried this method but this seems correct and elegant. Thank you so much for this valuable solution!

Comment: Thank you for appreciating! Unfortunately there was an issue with the initial version, which is now fixed, but loosing a little bit of the elegance. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since binary trees can be represented as linear expressions the binary tree

```
   n1
  /  \
 red n2
 / \  \
n3 n4  red
       / \
      n5 n6
```

can be represented as the linear expression `((n3 red n4) n1 (n2 (n5 red n6)))`

Now a linear expression for a binary tree can be represented as a BNF and `red` can be replaced with an `|` or operator

```
<s> ::= <a> n1 (n2 <b>)
<a> ::= n3 | n4
<b> ::= n5 | n6
```

Now all the possible combinations (walks) of this BNF are

```
n3 n1 (n2 n5)
n3 n1 (n2 n6)
n4 n1 (n2 n5)
n4 n1 (n2 n6)
```

and these can be turned back into the trees of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the algorithm:

```
node main_root_address; //address of very first node

function myfunc_inorder(root_address) //call this from main 
{
  if root_address is null return;

  myfunc_inorder(root_address->left);

  if(root_address->value is "red")
  {
    node temp = root_address;
    root_previous->parent = root_address->left;
    //inside each node along with value and pointer to left and right             subtree store the address of the parent node.
    myfunc_inorder(main_root_address);
    root_previous->parent = root_address->right;
    myfunc_inorder(main_root_address);
    root_address = temp;
  }

  myfunc_inorder(root_address->right);
}
```

**How this algorithm is working?**

First I will start with "node n1", then move to "node red" then to "node n3" then back to "node red"...Here I will replace "red" with left sub-tree and then with right sub-tree and repeat the algorithm until no red is left...